# Handling unknown number of aggregation operations

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to write a generic code that will create aggregations if needed for a query, depending on the filters I got from the API call.

So, for example, I might create 'match' aggregation for start_time field, but sometimes I won't.

My problem is that when calling `collection.aggregate(...)` I need to know exactly how much and which aggregations I want to call.

Is there a way to do it dynamically?

I tried passing 'null' or empty DBObject but that ended with an exception.

Comment: DBCollection#aggregate accepts a variable number of aggregation operations - so you can pass an array.

Comment: @isnot2bad do you want to answer the question so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `DBCollection#aggregate(DBObject, DBObject...)` accepts a variable number of aggregate options, so an array can be passed.

```
DBObject firstOp = ...;
DBObject[] otherOps = ...;
AggregationOutput result = collection.aggregate(firstOp, otherOps);
```

Note that the first argument is one single operation, so the array has to start at operation #2.